# How to determine if an MPI communicator is valid?

Tags: mpi

In my program, I have wrapped up some MPI communicators in to a data structure. Unfortunately, sometimes the destructor of an object of this type might get called before it has been initialized. In my destructor, I of course call `MPI_Comm_Free`. But if this is called on an invalid communicator the code crashes.

I've been looking through the MPI standard, but I can't find a function to test if a communicator is valid. I also assume I can't use `MPI_Comm_set_errhandler` to try and catch the free exception because there isn't a valid communicator to set the handler of. I could maintain a flag value of my own saying if the communicator is valid, but I prefer to avoid duplicating state information like that. Is there any built in way I can safely check if a communicator is valid?

Here is a basic program demonstrating my problem:

```
#include <mpi.h>
typedef struct {
  MPI_Comm comm;
} mystruct;


void cleanup(mystruct* a) {
  MPI_Comm_free(&(a->comm));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  mystruct a;

  /* Some early exit condition triggers cleanup without
     initialization */
  cleanup(&a);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_COMM_NULL` is a constant used for **invalid** communicators. However, you **cannot** determine if an MPI communicator **has been initialized**. In C, [it is **impossible** to determine if a variable has been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36490974/620382). [Non-static variables start with an *indeterminate* value, reading it causes *undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1597426/620382).

You **must** initialized the communicator with `MPI_COMM_NULL` yourself. This only make sense if cannot possibly create actual communicator during initialization.

Note: `MPI_Comm_free` also sets `comm` to `MPI_COMM_NULL`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense!